# Is there a way to not compile unit test function body in release build without using #ifdef?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

Let's say we have many unit test functions only for debug build. We don't want to compile these functions at all in release build. Is there a way other than wrapping unit test functions with #ifdef _DEBUG every time?

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
void testfunc_xxx() {
  ...
}
#endif
```

For example, we could have a macro

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define UNITTESTFUNC(name) void name()
#else
#define UNITTESTFUNC(name) template<typename T> void name()
#endif

UNITTESTFUNC(testfunc_xxx) {
  ...
}
```

But it depends on delayed template parsing. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to replace a simple macro with a complicated one? what is wrong with `ifndef` ?

Comment: Why would you even link the unit-test functions in the release build?  Just omit those object files in that version.  Better still, build the main part of the application as a library, that can be linked into the various test programs and into the releasable product.

Comment: Use your build system to select files for debug/release/both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another school of thought that separates production code from all unit test code keeping each in its own library.

The unit test code can then be built into its own application, calling the production code as a library.